# Airflow - Use run_id as volume name in DockerOperator

Tags: python, docker, airflow, mount

I wrote a DockerOperator in Apache Airflow and I want to give it a volume. So far so good. Here is an example:

```
t = DockerOperator(
        task_id='test',
        image='testimage:latest',
        command='python3 /code/test.py',
        volumes=["/mnt/interim:/interim"],
        xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag,
)
```

The problem I have is the following:

The name of the mounted directory needs to be flexible. Therefore, I want to mount a directory with the run_id in its name.

```
volumes=["/mnt/interim/" + "{{ run_id }}" + ":/interim"]
```

Airflow however does not seem to resolve "{{ run_id }}" in the volumes but only in the command of a DockerOperator.

To put it in a nutshell, I want to get the run_id in order to mount it.

Please note, using an airflow Variable (environment variable of airflow) wont do the trick, because if the task runs parallel, this Variable might get overwritten.

Maybe someone of you already knows an advanced DockerOperator that can do that (CustomOperator).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please paste complete dag .
Also {{run_id}} will only initialise in task. if you are trying to use run_id before any task in called it will not initialise

Comment: @JyotiArora what exactly do you need from the DAG, it consists of several tasks such as that DockerOperator and in the end all of them get executed in a row: t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4 >> t5 >> t6 >> t7. The DAG variable looks as follows:                dag = DAG(
        'lai',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='LAI DAG',
        schedule_interval=None,
        on_failure_callback=failure,
        on_success_callback=success,
    )

Comment: Did you try this:
volumes=["/mnt/interim/{{ run_id }}:/interim"]

From airflow Docs:
```

also_run_this = BashOperator(
    task_id='also_run_this',
    bash_command='echo "run_id={{ run_id }} | dag_run={{ dag_run }}"',
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: @JyotiArora I tried the first which is basically the same than explained above and the second one does not really make sense to me, because the output of the bash operator is not saved globally as far as I know but only in xcom values. Again, for getting the xcom values you use the brackets {{}} which did not work out.

Comment: There is a slack channel of apache airflow. you can join that and ask this question. There you will get quick response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Johannes for posting the question.

What you're trying achieve is possible, but because this isn't a very common use case this isn't enabled by default. The arguments that are in the `template_fields` iterable are being templated by Airflow. The `volumes` field isn't in there, so therefore it isn't being picked up.

The easiest way of doing this, is copy the docker_operator.py in your project, and add the `volumes` field to the list: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py#L126:

```
template_fields = ('command', 'environment', 'container_name', 'volumes',)
```

You can also open a ticket and get this merged up stream, but I'm not sure how many users will template this field. Hope this helps.